# How to open bootstrap datepicker to the left of input field at certain screen width

Tags: jquery, css, bootstrap-datepicker

I have several instances of bootstrap datepicker from [eyecon.ro](http://www.eyecon.ro/bootstrap-datepicker/) and I want to open some datepickers below (default) and some to the left of date input fields, where the move to the left is only at certain screen widths using a CSS `@media` query. I've tried using `addClass()` in the jQuery and also tried wrapping with a `div` with a class.

The media query to move the datepicker to the left is:

```
@media (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 1680px) {
    div.datepicker{ margin-top:-140px!important;margin-left:-220px!important;}
}
```

But at present, this is applied to all instances whereas I need it to be selective. Any ideas, please?

Comment: Can you add classes to your specific inputs?

Comment: This [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/nickwuk/eky5hosm/2/) shows my code but can't seem to make it work in it's minimal form. I could add another class to the specific inputs or just use their unique ids.

Answer (score 0):

If wrapping in a `div` with a class is a possibility, try CSS [`+`](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_element_pluss.asp) selector:

**HTML:**

```
<div class="datepicker-on-left">
  <div class="datepicker"><div/>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
@media (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 1680px) {
    div.datepicker-on-left + div.datepicker { 
      margin-top:-140px!important;
      margin-left:-220px!important;
    }
}
```

Comment: As mentioned in my question I've tried wrapping the datepicker in another div with a class but so far failed. I tried the following:
$( "#startdate" ).datepicker({
 format: "dd/mm/yyyy",
  autoclose: true,
  startDate: "today",
    beforeShow: function() {
   $(this).wrap('<div class="dpleft"/>');
   //$('.datepicker').wrap('<div class="dpleft"/>');
        }
 });

Answer (score 0):

The easy solution was to extend the bootstrap-datepicker.js script with one line of code in the constructor:

```
    if ('addClass' in options) { this.picker.addClass(options.addClass); }
```

Then initiate with:

```
<script>
$( "#startdate" ).datepicker({
    addClass: "dpleft"
});
</script>
```

And change css to:

```
@media (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 1680px) {
    div.datepicker.dpleft{ margin-top:-140px!important;margin-left:-220px!important;}
}
```